# The play, forward and backward buttons on my MacBook are inactive with VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player, macbook

The play, forward and backward buttons on my MacBook are inactive with VLC. What can I do to make them active?

Comment: Consider giving more details about the issue. For instance; what versions of VLC and macOS are you using? Also, what do you mean by "forward and backward" buttons? Are they the arrow/cursor keys?

Comment: Mojave 10.14.5 
VLC Version 3.0.7.1 Vetinari (Intel 64bit)
Play, backward and forward button on the top of the keyboard.